# Can I apply permissions through an ARM template?

Tags: azure, permissions

In Azure, if I want to give read-access for a resource group through RBAC, can I do that through an ARM template? I know it's possible through a VSTS build step or a PS script, but is there any way to give permissions through ARM templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>No, this is not posible due to the fact that REST call to apply permissions is something like this:</strike>

```
/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxx
```

You cannot replicate subscription "level" rest calls with an ARM template yet.

Welp, contrary to everything I know, this works:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "name": "8446a13c-6886-46e2-a17f-9df73adb334e",
            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
                "principalId": "user_guid_goes_here",
                "scope": "[resourceGroup().Id]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This assigns contributor role to the user with provided guid (principalId) to the resource group where you deploy the template. to assign other role get its guid and replace the contributor guid (b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c - well known guid). You can also assign permissions to specific resource. Use `scope` to do that (change it to resourceId). `Name` has to be a new guid.

I have no idea why this works, i will get back to you when i find out why it works.

Comment: What about the stuff in this documentation: https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/resource-manager-template-role.md?

I couldn't get it working, but are you sure it's only possible through REST calls?

Comment: check updated answer. i have no clue how it works, as it shouldn't ;)

Comment: Yes, this totally worked. I think mine was broken because I had the wrong apiVersion. For the name of the resource, I used a GUID generator, and it worked. Can you explain why the name of the resource needs to be a GUID?

Comment: because this is how the resource provider works. it assigns random guids to resouce names. and you have to mimic that behavior

Comment: If i want to put this step in multiple ARMs, do I need a unique GUID every time?

Comment: yes, there's the guid() function, but its deterministic, so you might want to calculate guid outside of the template.

Comment: In the code you posted, the scope was the entire resource group, and when I tried changing it to just one resource, I got an error saying the role assignment scope must match the scope specified on the URI.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-rbac-builtinrole-virtualmachine/azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 1):

One Important thing, We **can't** apply permission on **Subscription level** using ARM template. We can **only apply** permission on resource group and its resources.

Answer (score 0):

We can assign the permission on resource group and its resources.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
    "name": "[variables('roleName')]",
    "apiVersion": "[variables('authAPIVersion')]",
    "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
        "scope": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name)]"
    }     
}
```

Go to to this link for more Details - [Role-Based Access Control(RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)