# How to do a role assignment for the resourcegroup with arm templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have tried

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-07-01",
  "name": "[concat(resourceGroup().name,'/Microsoft.Authorization/',variables('principalId'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('owner')]",
    "principalId": "[parameters('msi').principalId]",
    "scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name)]"
  }
},
```

but it gives the following error

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource
>   'sf-gateway/Microsoft.Authorization/5e60879d-b9c0-4e11-9548-9d92ed244eef' for type 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments' at line '1' and
>   column '3432' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type
>   must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root
>   resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource
>   name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage
>   details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

I dont fully understand whats needed to be changed.

I want to give the principal ownership over the resourcegroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to give the principal ownership over the resourcegroup

You could get the template demo code from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-rbac-builtinrole-resourcegroup). If you create the template with VS you could get it directly from the template. It works correctly for me.

[image]
**azuredeploy.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "principalId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The principal to assign the role to"
      }      
    },
    "builtInRoleType": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Owner",
        "Contributor",
        "Reader"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Built-in role to assign"
      }      
    },
    "roleNameGuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "A new GUID used to identify the role"
      }      
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "Owner": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635')]",
    "Contributor": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
    "Reader": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7')]",
    "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('roleNameGuid')]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
        "scope": "[variables('scope')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "principalId": {
      "value": "principalId"
    },
    "builtInRoleType": {
      "value": "Owner"
    },
    "roleNameGuid": {
      "value": "Guid name"
    }
  }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because the name has more segments, i.e. components demarcated with a slash, than the type, as explained in more detail here: [Resolve errors for invalid template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors#solution-2---incorrect-segment-lengths).

There's a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284885/can-i-apply-permissions-through-an-arm-template); if you can get the GUID for the resource and pass that in for name, it will have fewer segments than the type.