# Configure ARM Template to Authorize Salesforce Connection Automatically

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

We currently have an ARM template that deploys a Logic App with a Salesforce connector.

The issue we face is that once the template is deployed we have to **manually** authorize the Salesforce connection:

[image]

Is it possible to add the authorization to the ARM Template? If so how would this be achieved?

Comment: Would this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284885/can-i-apply-permissions-through-an-arm-template

Comment: no, that is not the issue here @HariHaran. can you try this thing: https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for the link, unfortunately that does not solve the issue.

Comment: by authorizing you mean you add the credentials manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is impossible to authorize Salesforce Connection via the ARM template. We just could create the API connection via the template at most, the ARM template is based on the azure resources, it will not store your credential(e.g. username, password).

**Workarounds**:

1.You could separately create two templates for  Logic App and API connection, then you just need to authorize the connection once when it was deployed, let the logic app use the connection.

2.If you need to finalize the API Connection creation without opening every Logic App, you could try the powershell script [LogicAppConnectionAuth](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth), it will then open the consent link and complete authorization to enable a connection, see this [link](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html).

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and you simply need to add this to your ARM template under properties :

For Sandbox :

```
"ParameterValues": {
"token:LoginUri": "https://test.salesforce.com",
}
```

or this for production :

```
"ParameterValues": {
"token:LoginUri": "https://login.salesforce.com",
}
```

PS : you still have to authorize the connection manually once created.

Here is the full ARM template that works :

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
        "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
        "name": "salesforce",
        "location": "eastus",
        "properties": {
            "displayName": "Connection to Salesforce",
            "ParameterValues": {
                "token:LoginUri": "test.salesforce.com"
            },
            "api": {
                "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/salesforce')]"
            }
        }
    }
]
```